# sqlalchemy database creation error

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a project i am working on and i am getting a small error that is preventing me from creating all the tables and my database. I am getting the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/PayUp$ python setup_database.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_database.py", line 22, in <module>
    class Users(Base):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 50, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 227, in _as_declarative
    if not table.c.contains_column(c):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'
```

and the code that i am using is as follows:

```
#The following are all of the standard imports that are needed to run the database
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Index
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#The following is what will create the declarative_base base that will be imported to every tables
Base = declarative_base()

#The following is the user table which will store the users id and username
class Users(Base):
    __table__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_name = Column(String(16), nullable = False, unique = True, index = True)

class User_Auth(Base):
    __table__ = 'user_auth'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    last_name = Column(String(16), nullable = False)
    first_name = Column(String(16), nullable = False)
    password = Column(String(225), nullable = False)

class User_Info(Base):

    __table__ = 'user_info'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = Column(String(50), nullable = False, index = True, unique = True)
    phone = Column(Integer(12), nullable = True, unique = True)
    age = Column(Integer(2), nullable = False)
    gender = Column(String(2), nullable = True)

class User_Location(Base):
    __table__ = 'user_location'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    street = Column(String(200), mullable = False)
    city = Column(String(35), nullable = False)
    state = Column(String(3), nullable = False)
    zip_code = Column(Integer(5), nullable = False, index = True)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///payup.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried replacing __table__ with __tablename__

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html

Comment: yeah i totally forgot tot add name. It worked. thank you